# Can I delete (seemingly redundant) Program Files (x86), or Program Files folder, when running 64 bit win 8.1

Tags: windows, disk-space

I want to get rid of unnecessary files. I'm asking about the `Program Files` (11.1 GB) and `Program Files (x86)` (10.4 GB) folders They are about equal size. Do I need to keep both folders? If so, why?

[image: image1]

---

Does anything in this screenshot standout which would cause concern? My Pavilion dv6 runs great, then bogs severely, then may run great again after persisting and trudging through the 20-40 minute "bog". Otherwise, I shutdown. Later it's fine...for a while.

[image: image2]

---

I am wondering about the 6.5Gb file named "00000000" shown in this screenshot. What is it and do I need to keep it?

[image: image3]

Comment: If you delete the contents of Program Files then you remove your applications

Comment: Thanks Ramhound, Is the question about the 6.5 GB "00000000" file not specific enough? The question was  "what is it and do I need to keep it?" Thanks. PS I don't know what you mean by "Edit your question so your text isn’t one giant link, be specific about what your asking about, because it currently isn’t clear"

Comment: It’s a Chrome profile file, you can delete it, at the expense of whatever Chrome uses it for.  But you asked about Program Files x86 also...All your text is a url.  Your question still isn’t clear, so edit it, be specific with regards to what your asking.  Backup the profile folder, delete it, then restore your configuration changes to Chrome.  The file is likely a temporary file created for a purpose, what that purpose was, cannot be determined

Comment: 64 bit Windows can run both 32 and 64 bit applications.  32 bit applications are stored in one and 64 bit applications are stored in the other.

Comment: I've edited your question. Please review it to see if I've unintentionally changed any of your meaning. Please consider removing the part about the computer being slow and ask a separate question about that. Questions on this Q&A site need to be reasonably focused on a single issue, and performance is separate from questions about disk space usage.

Answer (score 1):

> *I'm asking about the "Program Files" 11.1 GB and "Program Files (x86)" 10.4 GB...*

You have a 64-bit version of Windows.
On 64-bit versions of Windows, by default:

- 64-bit applications are installed in `C:\Program Files`, and
- 32-bit applications are installed in `C:\Program Files (x86)`.

Don't be mislead by the fact they're similar in size. That's pure coincidence. And they're not redundant. While you may see identically-named folders in each Program Folder, closer inspection will reveal their content is actually different. For example, on my machine I have an Adobe folder in each Program Files files folder, but that's because I have some 64-bit and some 32-bit Adobe applications.

> *Do I need to keep both folders? If so, why?*

**Yes,** because actual applications installed on your computer are in these folders. If you delete them (or any of their contents), Bad Things™ will happen.

> *Here I was wondering about the 6.5Gb "00000000" file. What is it and do I need to keep it?*

You're referring to the file named **00000000** in your Google Chrome User Data folder. According to this [ghacks post](https://www.ghacks.net/2015/06/24/hard-drive-filling-up-check-chromes-file-system-folder/), this file is used by Chrome to store files with the help of the [File System API](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/fileSystem), which is part of HTML5. While the post claims you can delete the file outright, it also mentions that it can be delete by using the *Clear browsing data* dialog, which I would regard as a safer method for clearing unwanted profile data:

1. Load the `chrome://settings/` page in the Chrome browser.
2. Search for **clear** at the top.
3. Click on the **clear browsing data** button when the results are displayed.
4. Make sure **cookies and other site data** is selected. Please note that this will remove cookies from the browser which will log you out of any service you are currently signed in and may also remove web settings from Chrome.

[image]

---

> *Does anything in this screenshot standout which would cause concern? My Pavilion dv6 runs great, then bogs severely...*

Nothing in the screen shot tells us why your computer might be slow then fast then slow again. If you'd like to investigate that further, please [Ask another question](https://superuser.com/questions/ask) and include more details.